# AccessViolation Exception in vs2013 64bit not vs2010 64bit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit, dllimport

I'm getting System.AccessViolation Exceptions when running my code on VS2013 64 bit, framework 4+. It works when using an earlier framework or in 32 bit mode. It also works fine on both 32 bit and 64 bit on VS2010 with framework 4.

The culprit is in here somewhere:

```
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    IntPtr ptr;
    if(CPU.Is32Bit)
    {
        ptr = (IntPtr)(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt32() + index);
    }
    else
    {
        ptr = (IntPtr)(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt64() + Convert.ToInt64(index));
    }

    res = beEncodeChunk(hbeStream, nBytes / 2, ptr, pOutput, ref pdwOutput); //<--- Error here
```

in debugging it, ptr in vs2010 in 64 bit mode is a number like

35545824

whereas in vs2013 in 64 bit mode i'm getting

888151484352

it looks like the compiler in vs2013 is maybe using a different memory address space to vs2010. Am I doing something obviously stupid here or barking up completely the wrong tree?

Comment: There is no such thing as "VS2013 64bit". Are you referring to a 64bit compiled binary?

Comment: yes, building the application in 64 bit mode in vs2013

Comment: If `CPU.Is32Bit = false`, does thins mean the process is 64 bit?

Comment: yes it does, that whole if structure can actually be replaced with 

ptr = (IntPtr)(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt64() + index);

Answer (score 0):

It seems the version of lame i'm using is not truly 64 bit compatible and doesn't like having a 64 bit IntPtr passed into it. I've resolved my issue by using a newer version of the DLL along with this library:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio.Lame/